# Having if elif condition problems python2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement

When I run the following, with the conditions course level 6 with over 260 points and a 0 in maths I'm not getting the "Unfortunately you do not meet the requirements to progress to third level, At least 260 points and a pass in Mathematics are required." message.

But when run with the conditions course level 5 with over 260 points and 0 in maths I do get the message?

```
if course == 5:
    print"Your total CAO points are " ,total

elif course == 6:
        print"Your total CAO points are " , total*1.25
        total= total*1.25

if total >=260: 
    if math>=25:
        print "You are eligible to progress to third level"

elif total >=260:
     math=0
        print "Unfortunately you do not meet the requirements to progress to third level, At least 260 points and a pass in Mathematics are required."

elif total <=260:
    math=0
    print "Unfortunately you do not meet the requirements to progress to third level, At least 260 points and a pass in Mathematics are required."
```

Comment: Your `elif` is the same as your `if`

Comment: There are multiple problems. The first two conditions (involving `total`) are duplicates, and the last two overlap.

Comment: OP, can you specify the criteria used to determine passing/failing i.e. the formula you use to map course & points -> pass/fail?

Answer (score 1):

Once one test in an if-elif-else suite passes none of the other tests will be checked.  In your code the condition in your `elif` is identical to the one in your `if`.  That means the code under the `elif` will never be reached.

```
if total >= 260: 
    if math >= 25: # failing this if-statement does not negate the "if total >= 260"
        print "You are eligible to progress to third level"

elif total >= 260:  # will never be reached because it's identical to prior if-statement
    math=0
    print "Unfortunately you do not meet the requirements to progress to third level, At least 260 points and a pass in Mathematics are required."

elif total <= 260: # is 260 in our out? if 260 is a pass change from <= to <
    math=0
    print "Unfortunately you do not meet the requirements to progress to third level, At least 260 points and a pass in Mathematics are required."
```

There is a better way to write your conditions.  Your error message contains the word `and`:

> At least 260 points **and** a pass in Mathematics are required.

So use `and` in your condition to simplify your logic:

```
if total >= 260 and math >= 25:     # must meet both conditions
    print "You are eligible to progress to third level"
else:
    math = 0
    print "Unfortunately you do not meet the requirements to progress to third level. "\
        "At least 260 points and a pass in Mathematics are required."
```